# How to extract schema for avro file in python

Tags: python, schema, avro

I am trying to use the Python Avro library (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/avro) to read a AVRO file generated by JAVA. Since the schema is already embedded in the avro file, why do I need to specify a schema file? Is there a way to extract it automatically?

Found another package called fastavro(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fastavro) can extract avro schema. Is the manual specifying schema file in python arvo package by design? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14):

I use python 3.4 and Avro package 1.7.7

For schema file use:

```
reader = avro.datafile.DataFileReader(open('file_name.avro',"rb"),avro.io.DatumReader())
schema = reader.meta
print(schema)
```

Comment: This worked well with Python 2.7 as well.

My import statements are as follows (not sure how much you need):  
import avro.schema  
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader  
from avro.io import DatumReader

Answer (score 10):

A direct examination of `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/avro/datafile.py` reveals the answer:

```
reader = avro.datafile.DataFileReader(input,avro.io.DatumReader())
schema = reader.datum_reader.writers_schema
print schema
```

Curiously, in Java there is a special method for that: [`reader.getSchema()`](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/avro/generic/GenericDatumReader.html#getSchema%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

In my case in order to get the schema as a "consumable" python dictionary containing useful info such schema name and so on I did the following:

```
reader: DataFileReader = DataFileReader(open(avro_file, 'rb'), DatumReader())
schema: dict = json.loads(reader.meta.get('avro.schema').decode('utf-8'))
```

The `reader.meta` is a dictionary pretty useless "as is", since it contains 2 keys: `avro.codec` and `avro.schema` that are both `bytes` objects (so I had to parse it in order to access to properties).