# Produce Avro message from using classes

Tags: java, json, serialization, avro

As of now am creating avro message from `avsc` schema file. Using below code snippet

```
static byte[] fromJasonToAvro(String json, String schemastr) throws Exception {

        InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes());
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(input);

        Schema schema = Schema.parse(schemastr);

        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema, din);

        DatumReader<Object> reader = new GenericDatumReader<Object>(schema);
        Object datum = reader.read(null, decoder);

        GenericDatumWriter<Object> w = new GenericDatumWriter<Object>(schema);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        Encoder e = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(outputStream, null);

        w.write(datum, e);
        e.flush();

        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder jsb = new StringBuilder();

        ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("RsvpAvroSchema.avsc");
        InputStream js = classloader.getResourceAsStream("JsonMessage.dat");
        
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        InputStreamReader jisr = new InputStreamReader(js, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        BufferedReader jbr = new BufferedReader(jisr);
        br.lines().forEach(line -> sb.append(line));
        jbr.lines().forEach(line -> jsb.append(line));

        System.out.println(sb);
        System.out.println(jsb);
        
        System.out.println(new String(fromJasonToAvro(jsb.toString(), sb.toString()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

But I've created avro classes (data structure) too from `avsc` using maven plugin. But now not sure how to use that main class of `avro message data structure` with `string json` message to produce avro message ?

Can anyone share how to do it ?

Update:

How to create Avro object from string Json ? Already have avro classes available in my project.

2nd update

```
public class AvroInstance {

    static DecoderFactory DEFAULT_FACTORY = new DecoderFactory();
    static DatumReader<Object> reader = new GenericDatumReader<Object>(RSVP.SCHEMA$);
    static Object rsvpOB;

    public Object avroInstance(String JsonString) {

        try {
            rsvpOB = reader.read(null, DEFAULT_FACTORY.jsonDecoder(RSVP.SCHEMA$, JsonString));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rsvpOB;

    }
```

Comment: Where are you sending the Avro message to? A Kafka topic? If so, configure the Producer to use the KafkaAvroSerializer - see https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/serdes-avro.html

Comment: @Kevin I believe the intention is to not use a Registry https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67518900/produce-kafka-avro-messages-without-schema-registry-url

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your AVSC file reader with the static `SCHEMA` string stored in the generated class to get the same string...

You could also just use libraries that already do this

- https://github.com/allegro/json-avro-converter
- Jackson object mapping between JSON and it's own Avro support

Comment: I've updated my code the way you had suggest, please check in 2nd update in question AvroInstance. Does it looks fine to you ?

Comment: Seems okay, by why are you returning an `Object` instead of `RSVP` instance?

Comment: have modified to RSVP. But tell me one thing what does from_avro returns ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to. That's not part of my answer or your question... But that's a Spark method that would return a Dataframe