# Decode Avro decimal-as-bytearray string

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka, avro

I'm using Kafka with Avro messages. One of my fields is defined like this:

```
{ 
    "name": "a_number", 
    "type": "bytes", 
    "logicalType": "decimal", 
    "precision": 4, 
    "scale": 4 
}
```

Using the Avro console consumer, I see a message like this:

```
{"a_number": "\t\u0000°"}
```

Which I expect to equal `59`.

Supposedly, the bytearray [should be the twos-compliment of the number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray()). I've tried using Python's [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module to decode it, but the values I get don't make any sense:

```
bs = '\t\u0000°'.encode('utf8')    # b'\t\x00\xc2\xb0'
struct.unpack('>l', bs)[0] / 1e4   # 15104.4784
```

How can I validate the message? Can I decode the string somehow, or has the Avro console consumer corrupted it?

Comment: For comparison: `struct.pack('>l', int(59 * 1e4)) == b'\x00\t\x00\xb0'`

Comment: Are you sure that you want to encode high ASCII values as UTF-8? They will gain at least one additional byte, then, which will influence the total value. That said, at least you will *get* 4 bytes. Your sample string defines only 3.

Comment: @usr2564301 Yeah, I'm not sure - it does seem weird. The reason I chose UTF-8 is that that's what JSON uses to encode strings, and the output of the Avro console consumer is (apparently) JSON. I am a bit suss on that string; I would have expected it to write something in Base64 or so.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be going about this the Hard Way. The approach suggested by [How to extract schema for avro file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006273/how-to-extract-schema-for-avro-file-in-python) is to use:

```
reader = avro.datafile.DataFileReader(open('filename.avro',"rb"),avro.io.DatumReader())
schema = reader.meta
```

Single stepping in a debugger to see how the reader decodes your messages should get you closer to assembling a "raw" hand engineered decode.

Comment: Yep fair point. I don't have a `.avro` file to read, but maybe I should just write a little Python script using an `AvroConsumer` instead of the (presumably) Java-based console consumer to test it.